# How to protect a server's secret key on a browser?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, webcrypto-api

In this use case, the server send an encypted blob to the browser and the the javascript on the browser subsequently requests the decryption key from the server and decrypts the blob to usable content.

Is there a way to protect this key on the browser from an attack by a bookmarklet or browser plugin or the user stepping through the javascript debugger on browser? Or atleast make it a slightly harder problem for the attacker.

Edit : the context of the problem is HTML Video DRM as specified in EME specifications. There  is a ClearKey api that is part of this standard and does nor require   closed source plugin from  WideVine or  FairPlay etc. But as multiple responses have pointed out, ClearKey cannot be protected. (which unfortunately means using propritory DRM plugins).

Comment: Step 1. Make this user specific, so it will only work for that user.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); what are you ultimately trying to accomplish with this? Also, you may want to think about redesigning your security model.

Comment: I am looking for a way to protect the ClearKey used in HTML5 Encrypted Media Extensions.

Comment: @user193116 I'm not familiar with ClearKey, but if you want to protect it then it can never reach the client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **You can not guarantee the security of any data once it reaches the client.**

There is just no way to do this. Once the client receives this, especially if they also receive the decryption key, they have full access to all the secrets within.

On a very simple scale, they can just drop some breakpoint or put some `prints` in the javascript console. If they want to get more advanced they can use tools like wireshark to see the data as it comes over the wire.

Now if you want to send them encrypted data that doesn't get decrypted, and it is strongly encrypted, then its not *as* bad. But if you're never going to decrypt it on their side, then what are you even sending it for?

Answer (score 6):

Agree that it can't be done.  You could do it with asymmetric encryption.  But I would go back to why you're doing it - if the connection were SSL encrypted, there is no reason to do it.